# Using remove function in c

Tags: c

I have a problem with the `remove()` function. It is very simple program will copy the 2d matrix into `kimenet.txt` and I want to remove the `bemenet.txt`.

The question : why my program return -1 when it should be 0 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **a,n,i,j;
    FILE *fin,*fout;;
    fin = fopen("bemenet.txt","rt");
    if(!fin){printf("Error");return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    fout = fopen("kimenet.txt","wt");
    if(!fout){printf("Error");return EXIT_FAILURE;}
    fscanf(fin,"%i",&n);
    a = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for(j = 0; j <n; ++j){
            fscanf(fin,"%i",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            fprintf(fout,"%4i ",a[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fout,"\n");
    }
    int ret = remove("kimenet.txt");
    if(ret == 0){
        printf("Deleted succesfully");
    }
    else printf("Error");

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You try to remove the file while it is still open

Comment: You are removing `kimenet.txt`, not `bemenet.txt`. Also, the file might not be removable if you are on Windows (where you get a free mandatory lock with every open)

Comment: Instead of the pointer-to-pointer thing, consider using a 2D array. You can then read the whole file with one single call to `fread` and there will be no fragmentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't delete a file without closing it... use fclose to close the file first.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int **a, n, i, j;
    FILE *fin, *fout;;
    fin = fopen("bemenet.txt", "rt");
    if (!fin){ printf("Error"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    fout = fopen("kimenet.txt", "wt");
    if (!fout){ printf("Error"); return EXIT_FAILURE; }
    fscanf(fin, "%i", &n);
    a = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
        for (j = 0; j <n; ++j){
            fscanf(fin, "%i", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j){
            fprintf(fout, "%4i ", a[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(fout, "\n");
    }

    fclose(fin); //move fcloses here 
    fclose(fout);

    int ret = remove("kimenet.txt");
    if (ret == 0){
        printf("Deleted succesfully");
    }
    else printf("Error");


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```